# Web service authentication in SharePoint Office 365 compared to SharePoint BPOS?

Tags: authentication, office-365

On our public web site we have forms users can use to insert data into lists on our SharePoint BPOS site. We use the web services (authentication/lists) to do this and the piece of code to authenticate is:

```
public void authentication()
{
   Auth.Authentication authenticationObj = new Auth.Authentication();
   authenticationObj.Url = authServiceUrl;
   authenticationObj.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
   authenticationObj.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
   authenticationObj.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_authUserName, _authPassword);

   Auth.LoginResult result = authenticationObj.Login(_authUserName, _authPassword);
}
```

We just got migrated to Office 365 and now the result comes back with `PassWordDoesNotMatch` but I know the password match because I can log on to the site with it.

I did a google and it seems like this doing this kind of thing has changed  from BPOS to Office 365, am I correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it has changed from BPOS to 365 - 365 uses claims based authentication.

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjohnson/archive/2011/05/14/part-2-headless-authentication-with-sharepoint-online-and-the-client-side-object-model.aspx

Comment: thanks I got it working with wictor's solution, not sure how to get web from a different site collection than the top one though, if I use any other URL than http://ourdomain.sharepoint.com then I can't authenticate

Comment: what if you are on linux trying to authenticate with Sharepoint Online? Then what would you do?

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza - better ask this as a new question I think, its not a comment.